# Argmax along multiple axis at the same time in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a requirement where I want  `argmax` of a tensor along the axis where the axis is not a scalar but a list like following

```
tf.math.argmax(out, axis=[1,2])
```

which is of-course syntactically wrong and I got the following error

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: dim must be a scalar, but received tensor of shape: [2] [Op:ArgMax]

But, here is what I want.

```
out = tf.constant([[[-1,-7,-13,-19],[-4,-10,16,-22]],[[-12,8,-14,-20],[-5,-11,-17,23]],[[-3,-9,-15,-21],[-6,12,-18,-24]]])
```

For slice `out[0,:,:]`, max element is 16 with index 2.

For slice `out[1,:,:]`, max element is 23 with index 3.

For slice `out[2,:,:]`, max element is 12 with index 1.

Desired output `[2,3,1]`

Comment: Please provide some similar dummy tensor.

Comment: Please explain what you want to get from `out=tf.constant([[0, 1], [3, 2]])`

Comment: Added sample input and output

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have done.

```
[tf.math.argmax(tf.math.reduce_max(out[n], axis=0)).numpy() for n in range(out.shape[0])]
```

Please point out if there are efficient/better or even alternative ways.